# Modifying a variable in class that calls function of another class

Tags: c++

I have a problem, and I am almost certain I can find a solution by restructuring the code I have to eliminate the problem, but I was wondering if there was a way to achieve the same result with what I have right now.

Suppose we have class A:

```
class A
{
public:
    int thing;
    void dostuff();
    std::list<B> mList;
}

void A::doStuff()
{
    for(auto x : mList)
        x.doMoreStuff();
}
```

And then there is class B.

```
class B
{
    void doMoreStuff();
}
```

Is it possible in any way to make B's doMoreStuff change the 'int thing' variable of class A without passing the instance of class A to B or similar convoluted methods?

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to do it without that, or a superclass or something of that sort.

Comment: How should B know about A if it doesn't get a reference or pointer to A?

Comment: What is `B.doMoreStuff();` supposed to mean?

Comment: You could go down the 'static' route but then you'll be limited to a single variable 'thing' amongst all other instances of A

Comment: @juanchopanza Sorry about the confusion, I was in a hurry. Presumably it would be the instance of class B, also referred to as 'B'. I probably should edit that, and make it clearer.

Comment: @NeedForSleep please edit the question, and put more samples, as it stands now, it's quite unclear.

Comment: @zett42 When you put it like that, I feel silly for even asking the question. Is there no way to make B aware of A, without passing a reference or pointer?

Comment: @Need Could you add a little bit of background info? What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: I updated class A in a hurry. Please let me know if I missed something or made an error. As for what the code is supposed to do, is exactly that; I'd like to know if a call to a method on B, can change a variable on A without pointers or references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to change the value of a certain instance you'll have to reference.

Tho something you could do is use the return value of the method in B

```
class A
{
    int thing;
    B b;
    void dostuff() {
        thing += b.doMoreStuff();
    };
}

class B
{
    int doMoreStuff() {
       return 1;
    };
}
```

Or you can make either `int thing` or `void doMoreStuff()` a `static` so it can be accessed from class memory instead of instance memory like so:

```
class A
{
    static int thing;

    void dostuff() {
        B.DoMoreStuff();
    };
}


class B
{
    static void doMoreStuff() {
       A.thing += 2;
    };
}
```

Comment: There is an error in your code. you can't do `B b = new B();` it's either `B * b = new B();` or `B b;` and if you choose to do the first option with pointers you should also change `b.doMoreStuff();` to b->doMoreStuff();

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can by simply passing the address of the **int thing of A** for example:

```
B.doMoreThing(&myInt);
```

and the definition of doMoreThing would be: `doMoreThing(int * myInt)` and when modifying the value of the int inside the function you should do for example `*myInt+=5` the `*` is important to access the variable.

Comment: I guess that's the best I am going to get. I really hoped there was a way to do it without references -- for no particular reason.

Comment: I don't think so. I guess that this is the best way to do it. I don't really like the solutions making the variable static because it becomes accessible by everyone and everywhere

Comment: I switched the answer to the static one as that one achieves the same result without the reference.

I don't like the static either, but in my case, doMoreStuff() has about 5 lines of inputs, having to put a reference in just makes things a hell of a lot more complicated.

Comment: No problem but take care because declaring a variable as static makes it accessible from everywhere but also makes instantiated once which means that if you do `A a;  a.thing=9` and then do `A a2; a2.thing=46` that will also change the **a.thing** and makes it equal 46

Comment: I know, that's fine. I only need one a.thing-- it's practically a global variable anyway. This saves me the trouble of having to pass it by reference to other things.

Comment: Perfect then (Y) !

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to write to thing without a reference or a pointer to it. That said, thing is private anyway, so you'd need a setter. Alternatively you could make B a friend of A, or give B a pointer to member to thing.